# Advanced Formal logic / Automata Theory textbook

Tags: math, computer-science, logic, automata

I know this is more a Math/Formal Language/Automata/Computer science question than an a programming one, but I hope I can get some advice on a **comprehensible textbook** (not an indecipherable monograph) on formal logic beyond Propositional and Predicate Calculus. I’m especially interested in **monadic second order logic** and **Büchi Automata**.

For now, I’ve only found  [Automata theory and its applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=x8IqWNscScwC) by Bakhadyr Khoussainov, Anil Nerode. [Automata, logics, and infinite games](http://books.google.com/books?id=USAsFHuDvHwC) By Erich Grädel, Thomas Wilke (eds). And [Formal Models of Communicating Systems: Languages, Automata, and Monadic Second-Order Logic](http://books.google.com/books?id=n_yJB3-8F-YC) Benedikt Bollig....Way over my head.

Comment: I've found this paper as complimentary Resource :  Finite-state Automata on Infinite Inputs by Madhavan Mukund (http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/papers/tcs-96-2.html)

The paper deals more with Büchi Automata than monadic second order logic.

Comment: I'm getting near : Elements of Finite Model Theory (http://books.google.com/books?id=zsJlEK4nK7sC) by Leonid Libkin is almost readable.

Comment: I'm not too sure how well connected these two subjects are.  Monadic Second Order Logic is part of mathematics, particularily metamathematics (foundation, logic & set theory).  Buchi Automata, is from Computer Science, Computability theory, I think.  I realize that  CS & Math are still pretty close, but I do not really see why you expect that there would be a book on both of these subjects.

Comment: "Automata on infinite objects  were introduced in the early 1960's by Buchi, motivated by issues in mathematical logic, viz., the decidability of his monadic second order theory of one successor  (S1S). […]. By the end of the 1960's, Rabin had shown how automata  on infinite trees, a natural but very powerful generalization of Buchi's automata on strings, could be used to show decidability of a surprisingly rich class of logical theories including the basic monadic second  order theory of multiple successors (SnS)."
Emerson, The Role of Buchi's Automata in Computing Science

Comment: I've found this interesting paper : Languages, Automata and Logic by Wolfgang Thomas (http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa05/cs598mp/LangAutomataLogic.pdf). Keywords : Finite automata, monadic second-order logic,Büchi automata. The math is still a little cryptic but understandable with a little work (I think).

Comment: Fair enough.  But still, it's so esoteric that an entire book seems like a long shot, esp. if you're limited to English.  Papers seems more likely.  But you might get lucky ... :-)

Answer (score 6):

So this is the best curriculum I can come with :

**For Beginners in Logic :**

Peter J. Cameron, *Sets, Logic and Categories*, Springer, Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series, 1999, [URL](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/slc/).

James L. Hein, *Discrete Structures, Logic, and Computability*, Jones & Bartlett Publishers, 2009 (3th ed) [URL](http://discretestructures.jbpub.com/).

> Logic for the computer scientist.

**For Beginners in Automata and Formal Langugage :**

Michael Sipser, *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, Course Technology, 2005 (2nd), [URL](http://www-math.mit.edu/~sipser/book.html).

**and**

Alan P. Parkes, *Introduction to Languages, Machines, and Logic*,  Springer, 2002.

**and**

Peter Linz, *An introduction to formal languages and automata*, Jones & Bartlett Publishers, 2000 (3 ed) [URL](http://www.jbpub.com/catalog/9780763737986/).

**and**

John E. Hopcroft and  Jeffrey D. Ullman, *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computation*,  Addison Wesley , 1979, (1st ed), ISBN :  0-201-02988-X; [URL](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/ialc.html).

**Intermediate level Logic (undergraduate):**

D. Ebbinghaus , *Mathematical Logic*, Springer, [URL](http://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&dq=Mathematical+Logic+By+H.+Ebbinghaus&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

**or**

Elliott Mendelson, *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, [URL](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZO1p4QGspoYC&dq=Mathematical+Logic+By+H.+Ebbinghaus&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

**Advanced level (Graduate):**

Wolfgang Thomas, *[Languages, Automata and Logic](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs686/2003sp/Thomas/thomas.ps)*, 1996.

Leoni Libkin, *Elements of Finite Model Theory*, Springer, 2004, [URL](http://books.google.com/books?id=n_yJB3-8F-YC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_navlinks_s), [TOC](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783540212027-t1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-117471-p30739332).

**For Research**

Benedikt Bolli, *Formal models of communicating systems*, Springer, 2006, [URL](http://books.google.com/books?id=n_yJB3-8F-YC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Grädel, Erich; Thomas, Wolfgang; Wilke, Thomas (Eds.), *Automata, logics, and infinite games*, Springer, 2002, [URL](http://www.springer.com/computer/book/978-3-540-00388-5),

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about Michael Sipser's [*Introduction to the Theory of Computation*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/053494728X). I actually have it right in front of me, although I haven't started reading it yet.

Comment: Spiser’s is a very nice book in Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation but it’s very basic and don’t  treat formal logic.

My title is a bit misleading. It’s just there a relation between monadic second order logic and Büchi Automata.

Comment: I myself found that book a bit confusing - examples were too 'perfect' and figures/examples were not explained as well as I would have liked. imho!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have specific topic you want from a book, so I looked into the index of some books in Amazon. Although I've never read this one, [Theory of Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846282977) by Dexter C. Kozen might interest you.

```
Büchi automation, 155, 159, 161, 283, 298, 343
      determinization, 167-170

monadic second-order theory
    of n successors, 154
    of successor, 154-159
```

The covered pages are in [Lecture 25 Automata on Infinite Strings and S1S](http://www.springerlink.com/content/t51840471507366k/), the first page is available for preview from the link.

[Theory of Computation http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JKHJGWBRL._BO2,204,203,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51JKHJGWBRL._BO2,204,203,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

Comment: The books looks interesting but the lecture format and the numerous (unrelated) subjects presented and the scarcity of the presentation of S1S make it not a very good solution.

Comment: Languages, Automata and Logic by Wolfgang Thomas is the best presentation I've found for now.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite what you're looking for, but I learned a great deal from Blackburn et al's [Modal Logic](http://www.mlbook.org/), and I learned what I know of automata from Jurafsky and Martin's [Speech and Language Processing](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~martin/slp.html), esp. Chapter 2. If nothing else, both provide excellent groundwork for further research.

Comment: I know Speech and Language Processing and that’s not what I’m looking for :) But I’ll take a look at the Blackburn book.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading about Büchi Automata in [Principles of Model Checking](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11481), which seems like a pretty good book. Of course, the focus is on the application to model checking, but model checking is mostly logic anyway.

Comment: I’ve found the TOC (http://www.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/tocs/19825007X.pdf), the books looks interesting in its own right but I’m afraid that the "Model Checking" bias is not what I’m looking for. 

What level of mathematical maturity is required to skim through it ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be a little surprised, but I think the book you're looking for is Foundations of Databases by Abiteboul, Hull and Vianu (also known as the "Alice book", because Alice is painted on its cover and stars in chapter-introduction dialogs with the authors). It's not a book about SQL, but about the theory of databases -- logic and its implementation in programs and functions -- so it spends quite a lot on issues of complexity and computability of query languages; and the authors make a great effort to be friendly and communicative.